# Should accents be used before or after boldface?

Tags: notation, vectors

Formally speaking, should accents above variables (e.g. tildes, hats and dots; $\tilde a,\hat a,\dot a$) be used before or after a boldface command when I want to use them on a vector? So what is correct in the following for lines; the ones on the left (accent before boldface), or the ones on the right (accents after boldface, making the accents themselves boldface as well)?
\begin{align}
\tilde{\mathbf{a}},\mathbf{\tilde{a}}\\
\hat{\mathbf{a}},\mathbf{\hat{a}}\\
\dot{\mathbf{a}}, \mathbf{\dot{a}}
\end{align}

Comment: That seems like a question of personal preference or a question to ask an editor.  Different journals might even follow different conventions.  It makes no difference to me.  You might get a good response asking this over on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) as well, though this is more a question on what standard practice is rather than how to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: If I'm thinking about $\dot f$ standing for the derivative, I would not put the dot in boldface, because the derivative is a "universal" operation which, contingently, applies to a vector. However, I'm pretty sure of having seen $\mathbf{f'}$ somewhere (perhaps Rudin). Other than that, I don't see an argument against any of the possibilities.

Comment: All notation is historical conventions. This is about a matter of opinion, not mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. I'll indeed also ask on [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). I thought that there is perhaps a standard convention on this in mathematics. I can also see what you mean with it being different for an accent representing an operation like differentiation.